# Sort by date in descending order echoed file directory in PHP

Tags: php

Ok I have a directory with files named by date with the extension ".html".

What I am trying to do is list the contents of the directory, minus the file extension, ordered by date with newest on top.

I have been fiddling with the below code for hours.

```
    <?php

if ($handle = opendir('update_table_cache')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {



        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." ) {

        $dirFiles[] = $entry ;
        rsort($dirFiles);
foreach($dirFiles as $entry) {

$withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $entry);

            echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/update_table_cache/'.$entry.'">'.$withoutExt.'</a><br>';
            }
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

This outputs something like this:

```
2016-01-18
2016-01-19
2016-01-18
```

There should only be one 2016-01-18 and it should be at the bottom. Why is there an extra 2016-01-18 at the top?

Edit: ok I changed it to the following:

```
<?php

    if ($handle = opendir('update_table_cache')) {

$dirFiles[] = $entry ;
            rsort($dirFiles);
    foreach($dirFiles as $entry) {

        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {



            if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." ) {



    $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $entry);

                echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/update_table_cache/'.$entry.'">'.$withoutExt.'</a><br>';
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }
    ?>
```

But this outputs:

```
2016-01-18
2016-01-17
2016-01-19
```

(I added another file "2016-01-17.html")

Comment: In your second code, you are only sorting an empty array – makes no sense. You need to put the values into the array _within_ your loop over the directory contents, then sort it, and then use a second loop to output the elements of the sorted array.

Comment: Still have no idea how to do that. I'm trying everything I can think of here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+readdir+sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
<?php

 $dir = opendir('update_table_cache');        // Open the sucker

$files = array();
while ($files[] = readdir($dir));
sort($files);
closedir($dir);

foreach ($files as $file) {

      //MANIPULATE FILENAME HERE, YOU HAVE $file...

      if ($file != "." && $file != ".." ){
      $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file);
      echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/update_table_cache/'.$file.'">'.$withoutExt.'</a><br>';
      }
}
?>
```

Thanks to user CBroe for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the output in the middle of the loop...

First you sort one element and print it, then sort two elements and print it.

Do the output after the loop.

Comment: This makes sense but I don't know how to do that, I'm very new at PHP and don't really work much with arrays..

Comment: that is quite vague, and what I tried did not work, I added more to the original post to show you what I've done

Comment: You have to sort and print **after** the `while` loop.

Comment: ok that worked, I posted the solution as an answer, thanks for your help